# Equivalence between an improper integral and a Riemann sum

Tags: calculus

My question is if

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{\left\lfloor\dfrac n k \right\rfloor + 1}\dfrac{1}{n} = \int^1_0 (-1)^{\left\lfloor\dfrac 1 x \right\rfloor+1} \, dx$$

when $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor = \operatorname{floor}(x)$.

The right improper integral exists, and it converges to $2\log2-1.$

Thanks in advance!